# Recommended way to read an entire table (Lambda, DynamoDB/S3)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to AWS and am working on a Serverless application where one function needs to read a large array of data. Never will a single item be read from the table, but all the items will routinely be updated by a schedule function.

What is your recommendation for the most efficient way of handling this scenario? My current implementation uses the `scan` operation on a DynamoDB table, but with my limited experience I'm unsure if this is going to be performant in production. Would it be better to store the data as a JSON file on S3 perhaps? And if so would it be so easy to update the values with a schedule function?

Thanks for your time.

PS: to give an idea of the size of the database, there will be ~1500 items, each containing an array of up to ~100 strings

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the size of each item, but how?

First of all to use DynamoDB or S3 you pay for two services (in your case*):

1- Request per month

2- Storage per month

If you have small items the fist case will be up to 577 times cheaper if you read items from DynamoDB instead of S3

How: $0.01 per 1,000 requests for S3 compared to 5.2 million reads (up to 4 KB each) per month for DynamoDB. Plus you should pay $0.01 per GB for data retrieval in S3 which should be added up to that price. However, your writes into S3 will be free while you should pay for each write into your DynamoDB (which is almost 4 times more expensive than reading).

However if your items require so many RCUs per reads maybe S3 would be cheaper in this case.

And regarding the storage cost, S3 is cheaper but again you should see how big your data will be in size as you pay maximum $0.023 per GB for S3 while you pay $0.25 per GB per month which is almost 10 times more expensive.

**Conclusion**:
If you have so many request and your items are smaller its easier and even more straight forward to use DynamoDB as you're not giving up any of the query functionalities that you have using DynamoDB which clearly you won't have in case you use S3. Otherwise, you can consider keeping a pointer to objects' locations stored in S3 in DynamoDB.

(*) The costs you pay for tags in S3 or indexes in DynamoDB are another factors to be considered in case you need to use them.

Comment: Hi @mok, thanks for your response! The total amount of data won't be huge.. at most a few MB. There will be lots of requests to the database - do you know if a `scan` (fetching the whole table) is equal to `get`ting a single item in terms of cost? Because the `scan` is a single request? If so, I may stick with DynamoDB for the ease of use like you've mentioned. Thanks again.

Comment: I have done some more research and found that a single `scan` can use up to 128 read operations for each MB of data. With that in mind, considering that if there were a sudden spike in traffic, querying for 1-2mb of data per user, I'm thinking that that could get costly. For that reason I'm leaning back towards storing the data as json. Let me know if you think I've misunderstood the pricing scheme. thanks

Comment: @sherlock Each scan processes each item individually, so one scan may (and perhaps will) consume more than one RCU. So, still you should check either the size of your items and the number of requests.

Comment: thank you for your clarification, I'll continue to do some research. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do:

**Schedule Updates:**

Lambda (to handle schedule changes) --> DynamoDB --> DynamoDBStream --> Lambda(Read if exists, Apply Changes to All objects and save to single object in S3)

**Read Schedule:**

With Lambda Read the single object from S3 and serve all the schedules or single schedule depending upon the request. You can check whether the object is modified or not before reading the next time, so you don't need to read every time from S3 and serve only from memory.

**Scalability:**

If you want to scale, you need to split the objects to certain size so that you will not load all objects exceeding 3GB memory size (Lambda Process Memory Size)

Hope this helps.

**EDIT1:**

When you cold start your serving lambda, load the object from s3 first and after that, you can check s3 for an updated object (after certain time interval or a certain number of requests) with `since modified date` attribute.

You can also those **data to Lambda memory and serve from memory** until the object is updated.

Comment: Ah that's a great idea to maintain both in this way! Thanks! Regarding serving from memory, is there a particular method of ensuring that this happens? I thought I'd have to `fetch` from S3 every time, does lambda have a kind of caching system?

Comment: Thanks for your clarification! Serving from memory would be ideal because the source data will reliably only need to be updated once a day. However, I can't find any documentation that explains how Lambda memory works. If I use S3.getObject() will this automatically store the data in memory? If not, your help in understanding how Lambda memory works would be really appreciated.

Comment: You need to go through S3 documentation and Lambda Documentation on how to move forward with this. Anytime you hit a roadblock feel free to ask questions in stackoverflow. Make sure you try and experiment it first.

Comment: Fair enough, I will do that - thanks again for your support!